# when moving element in DOM, does that element remain state?

Tags: javascript

```
<ul id="task1">
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="input1"><label>Item task1></label></li>
  ... some other <li> go here
</ul>

<ul id="task2">
  <li><input type="checkbox"><label>Item task2></label></li>  
   ...
</ul>

var task1 = document.getElementById("task1");
var task2 = document.getElementById("task2");
var moveFromTask1to2 = function() { task2.appendChild(this.parentNode); }
var moveFromTask2to1 = function() { task1.appendChild(this.parentNode); }
var bindElement(listItem, task) {
  var checkbox = listItem.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]");
  checkbox.onchange = task;
}

for (var i = 0; i < task1.children.length; i++) { bindElement(task1.children[i], moveFromTask1to2); //(1)
for (var i = 0; i < task2.children.length; i++) { bindElement(task2.children[i], moveFromTask2to1); //(2)
```

When I check the `input1` checkbox, it should move from `task1` to `task2`.
and it does that.

But when I check the `input1` checkbox again, it doesn't move from `task2` back to `task1`

can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that checkboxes from the first list `#task1` are moved to the list `#task2` on change event. After that has happened and on the subsequent change events, checkboxes are still moved to the same list, because events handler is the same. That's why you can't move checkboxes back to the initial list.

To fix it you can write one function instead of two `moveFromTask1to2` and `moveFromTask2to1`. For example:

```
var moveFromTo = function() {
    var moveTo = this.parentNode.parentNode === task1 ? task2 : task1;
    moveTo.appendChild(this.parentNode);
};
```

Check the demo below.

```js
var task1 = document.getElementById("task1");
var task2 = document.getElementById("task2");

var moveFromTo = function() {
    var moveTo = this.parentNode.parentNode === task1 ? task2 : task1;
    moveTo.appendChild(this.parentNode);
}

var bindElement = function(listItem, task) {
    var checkbox = listItem.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]");
    checkbox.onchange = task;
}

for (var i = 0; i < task1.children.length; i++) { bindElement(task1.children[i], moveFromTo); } //(1)
for (var i = 0; i < task2.children.length; i++) { bindElement(task2.children[i], moveFromTo); } //(2)
```

```html
<ul id="task1">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="input1" />
        <label>Item task11></label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="input1" />
        <label>Item task12></label>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul id="task2">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <label>Item task21></label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <label>Item task22></label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You bound an event handler to the object called `moveFromTask1to2`.

None of your code removes that event handler and adds `moveFromTask2to1`.

JavaScript doesn't time travel. It won't undo what your  `for` loops did and rerun them just because the data that they ran on in the past has changed since then.

---

You should probably solve this by using a single event handler function which, rather than hard coding the from and to elements, works them out based on the value of `this.parentNode`.

Comment: does that mean when moving element around DOM, that element won't change state even I add it to a group of new state. I mean that input1 still bind to moveFromTask1to2 even I added it to task2 that have moveFromTask2to1 event hander for each of its elements

Comment: It changes *state*. The `parentNode` changes. It appears in the new spot on the DOM. It won't change what event handlers are bound to it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that the event doesn't automagically change when you click the checkbox. It still has the same event handler, which moves it from task1 to task2.

Solution 1: assign a new event handler after move:

```
var moveFromTask1to2 = function() { 
  task2.appendChild(this.parentNode); 
  this.onchange = moveFromTask2to1;
}
var moveFromTask2to1 = function() { 
  task1.appendChild(this.parentNode); 
  this.onchange = moveFromTask1to2;
}
```

Solution 2: make the event handler more generic so it becomes a single 'toggle' function:

```js
var task1 = document.getElementById("task1");
var task2 = document.getElementById("task2");

var moveItem = function() { 
  var task = this.parentNode.parentNode;
  if (task == task1)
    task2.appendChild(this.parentNode);
  else
    task1.appendChild(this.parentNode);
}

var bindElement = function(listItem) {
  var checkbox = listItem.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]");
  checkbox.onchange = moveItem;
}

for (var i = 0; i < task1.children.length; i++) { bindElement(task1.children[i]);} //(1)
for (var i = 0; i < task2.children.length; i++) { bindElement(task2.children[i]);} //(2)
```

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<ul id="task1">
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="input1"><label>Item task1></label></li>
 
</ul>

<ul id="task2">
  <li><input type="checkbox"><label>Item task2></label></li>  
   ...
</ul>
```

You will note though, that the moving works, but the state (i.e. 'checked') is remembered for the checkbox. You might reset that in code, but actually I think this is a pretty crappy solution from a UX perspective. A checkbox is for checking/selecting an element. It shouldn't *do* anything. If you want to be able to move a listitem to another list, you should use a button instead.

That doesn't change the answer though. If you change the checkboxes to buttons and use the onclick event instead of onchange, the same answer applies. Technically it's almost the same as the snippet above, but from a user perspective this makes so much more sense:

```js
var task1 = document.getElementById("task1");
var task2 = document.getElementById("task2");

var moveItem = function() { 
  var task = this.parentNode.parentNode;
  if (task == task1)
    task2.appendChild(this.parentNode);
  else
    task1.appendChild(this.parentNode);
}

var bindElement = function(listItem) {
  var button = listItem.querySelector("input[type=button]");
  button.onclick = moveItem;
}

for (var i = 0; i < task1.children.length; i++) { bindElement(task1.children[i]);} //(1)
for (var i = 0; i < task2.children.length; i++) { bindElement(task2.children[i]);} //(2)
```

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<ul id="task1">
  <li><input type="button" value="Move"/><label>Item task1></label></li>
 
</ul>

<ul id="task2">
  <li><input type="button" value="Move"><label>Item task2></label></li>  
   ...
</ul>
```